# Let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix with $\operatorname{trace}(A)=3$ and $\det(A)=2$ . If $1\in \sigma(A)$ then what is $\sigma(A^2-2I)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix with $\operatorname{trace}(A)=3$ and $\det(A)=2$ . If $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then what are the eigenvalues of the matrix $A^2-2I$?

My attempt:

I had calculated and got eigenvalues as $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$. Can someone explain how to solve this problem?

Comment: How did you arrive at $\pm\sqrt 2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ be other two eigenvalues of $A$.

We have $$\lambda_1 +\lambda_2 + 1 = \operatorname{Tr} A = 3$$
$$\lambda_1\cdot\lambda_2\cdot 1 = \det A = 2$$

so $\lambda_1\lambda_2 = 2$ and $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 2$.

We get $\lambda_1(2-\lambda_1) = 2$ which gives $\lambda_1 = 1\pm i$ and then $\lambda_2 = 2 - \lambda_1 = 1\mp i$.

Therefore $\sigma(A) = \{1+i, 1-i, 1\}$.

Now use the spectral mapping theorem: $$\sigma(A^2 - 2I) = \sigma(A)^2 - 2 = \{(1+i)^2-2, (1-i)^2- 2, 1^2-2\} = \{2i-2, -2i - 2, -1\}$$

Comment: This is a very nice answer!